# Rate of change problem with velocities

Tags: chain-rule, pythagorean-triples

I can't seem to get this problem right. 
[image: problem]

Can someone help me with the formula for $$ \frac {df}{dt} $$

Comment: What do you know about the chain rule for functions with several variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $\theta =\pi/3$,

$$ f=\sqrt{x^2+y^2-xy}$$

Take the time derivatives $f’=f_x’x’+f_y’y’$,

$$f’ = \frac12 \frac {(2x-y)x’ + (2y-x)y’}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-xy}}$$

Then, plug in $x=28$, $y=12$, $x’=-2$ and $y’=-5$ to obtain

$$f’ = \frac12 \frac {(56-12)\cdot (-2)+ (24-28)\cdot (-5)}{\sqrt{28^2+12^2-28\cdot 12}}= -\frac{17\sqrt{37}}{74}$$

Comment: I already tried this answer but for some reason it says it is wrong. Any other thoughts? @quanto

Comment: @Alex.G - Just realized that algebraically $x'$ and $y'$ take negative values since both distances are decreasing.